# Format date from the following string in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, string, datetime, format

I'm new to coding in asp.net and I'm struggling to format the date I've managed to pull from our CRM content pages' live date. I've wrote the following code that manages to pull and display the date the page was created:

```
TheDate = DR["LiveDate"].ToString();
```

But it formats the date and time like this:

```
13/11/2012 00:00:00
```

How can I modify my above code to just display the date like so:

```
Tuesday, 13 November 2012
```

Or, just without the time

```
13/11/2012
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `DR` is a `DataRow`, isn't it?

If `DR["LiveDate"]` is already a `DateTime` column don't convert it to a localized string via `ToString`. Just cast it accordingly, for example via `Field` extension method:

```
DateTime dt = DR.Field<DateTime>("LiveDate");
```

If it's not a `DateTime` but a string you have to parse it to `DateTime`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(DR.Field<String>("LiveDate"));
```

If you want `Tuesday, 13 November 2012` as result use:

```
string result = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want `13/11/2012` use:

```
string result = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

or

```
string result = dt.ToString("d");
```

if your culture uses `/` as separator

otherwise

```
string result = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Further informations: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Although this code validated, it didn't work when debugging the preview page. The date stayed in the same format.

I also had problems with the last bit "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" - this didn't show in the intellisense. Maybe I haven't declared something.

Comment: @GBrooksy: you have to add `using System.Globalization;` at the top of the file or qualify it fully `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. I don't know what you mean with `debugging the preview page`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've done the above and now the date just doesn't show at all. 
"Debugging the preview page" = previewing the result.

Comment: @GBrooksy: use the debugger instead of a "preview page"(whatever that is). Maybe that preview page catches exceptions and shows only an empty string. It's also not clear where your code is located at all.

Comment: I have a server tag on the .aspx page:  `<%=TheDate%>`
    
With the codebehind file (.aspx.cs) that has the above code:  
`DataRow DR = myDATABASE.GetDataRow("select * from Pages where WID=*** and id=" + PageID);  
            DateTime dt = DR.Field<DateTime>("LiveDate");  
            string result = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Just in-case anyone has this problem and would like to know how I solved it, I'll post below.

@Tim Schmelter: I'm sure your answers were correct in some way as I tried them out in several instances but couldn't get the desired answer. Thanks for your time as it helped me to further debug my issue and get to a solution.

Here's my solution:

    `if (DR["LiveDate"] != System.DBNull.Value)

                {

                TheDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DR["LiveDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); ​

                }`

Comment: @GBrooksy: sorry, i didn't notice that you've already commented. I'm glad that you've got it working. Note that `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` will not work if your current culture date-separator sometime will be different than `/`. If you want to enforce `/` as separator you have to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as second parameter in `ToString`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator Here in germany for example i would get `13.11.2012` with your date and `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`.

Answer (score 0):

for your second question, try

```
TheDate = DR["LiveDate"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: Which will replace all `/` with your culture's actual date-separator if it's different (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator).

Comment: This doesn't validate for me, I get... "Error: no overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: @GBrooksy: because `DR["LiveDate"]` is an object not a `DateTime`